# Wordpress admin Tables use to display own data - In admin WP

Tags: table, wp-list-table

I want to display results in a table. Is it possible to use the wordpress tables like the one in the post and page section which shows all posts and pages in the admin section.

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mydonationdata";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name."";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result )
{
    echo $result->First_Name;
    echo $result->Last_Name;
    echo $result->Amount;
    echo $result->Email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the complex tables in admin are produced using [`WP_List_Table`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class. Despite being formally private, it has been widely used by third party extensions for years now.

It's not exactly friendly to work with, so you should research it and consider if your requirements merit reusing it or just replicating markup to achieve same visual look.